# Nested Scroll Effect in android with backward compativility

Tags: java, android, animation, scroll

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if9qBW_nIxM&feature=youtu.be

i am working on Scrolling effect like default android calling App in lollipop.but i am not able to get smoothness like in default app.i am posted a link please check it.This is what i have achieved .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_city_selection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrap_total_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_search_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_fav_ripple"
                android:background="@drawable/searchview_rounded"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/search" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_outlet_edittxt"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:hint="Search for outlets"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_overlay_txt"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/more" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.competent.groove.thegroove.utils.RippleView
                android:id="@+id/show_fav_ripple"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                app:rv_framerate="10"
                app:rv_rippleDuration="400"
                ripple:rv_type="rectangle"
                ripple:rv_zoom="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/show_fav_txt"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />
            </com.competent.groove.thegroove.utils.RippleView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pp_seacrh_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/searchview_rounded"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
           >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pp_search_img"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/search" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pp_search_outlet_edittxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:hint="Search for outlets"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pp_menu_overlay_txt"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/more" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.competent.groove.thegroove.utils.RippleView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rv_framerate="10"
            app:rv_rippleDuration="400"
            ripple:rv_type="rectangle"
            ripple:rv_zoom="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/select_city_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/city_selector_curve"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="I am in CHANDIGARH" />
        </com.competent.groove.thegroove.utils.RippleView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pp_main_fragment_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pp_top_header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="PARTY PARTNER"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_dots_txtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my requirement is

[image]